# Дублируется записи при добавлении в базу под wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax, база-данных

Есть сайт на `wordpress`, установлен плагин произвольных записей [acf](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), своя тема и созданный кастомный тип записей *отзывы*.
На странице запрашиваю от пользователя данные для публикации отзыва (имя, профессия, город, фото) и с помощью `ajax` переадресовываю на страницу, где заполняю необходимые поля и записываю в базу.

Запись создается, но, при этом публикуется дважды: первая без фото, вторая с.
Грешу на то, что функции `wp_insert_post` и `media_handle_upload` дублируют другу друга, но не знаю как это обойти.

**add_review.php**

```
// Подключаем необходимые файлы 
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

// Получение отправленных данных 
$user_name    = trim($_POST['name']);
$user_message = trim($_POST['message']);
$user_job = trim($_POST['job']);
$user_city = trim($_POST['city']);
$user_photo = trim($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$location = wp_upload_dir()['path']."/".$user_photo;
$post_data = array(
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_status'   => 'pending',               # статус - «На утверждении» 
    'post_type'     => 'reviews',               # тип записи - «Отзывы» 
    'post_title'    => 'Отзыв - ' . $user_name, # заголовок отзыва 
    'post_content'  => $user_message,           # текст отзыва 
    // 'tax_input' => ['{Название таксономии}' => array($review_type)], 
);

// Вставляем запись в базу данных 
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'photo', 0 );

update_field( 'review_name', $user_name, $post_id );      # имя 
update_field( 'review_job', $user_job, $post_id );        # профессия 
update_field( 'review_city', $user_city, $post_id );      # город 
update_field( 'review_photo', $attachment_id, $post_id );    # фото
```

**js**

```
$('#add_review').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var photo = $('#review_file')[0].files[0];

    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    formData.push({photo: 'photo'});

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/credit7/includes/add_review.php',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Спасибо. Ваш отзыв отправлен.',data);
            $(this).trigger('reset'); // очищаем поля формы 
        },
        error: function() { 
            console.log('Ошибка отправки.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А ты не пробовал передавать в `media_handle_upload` `$post_id`? Говорят, что помогает

Comment: @Сергей Валерьевич вместо `0` так `$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'photo', $post_id );` ? Пробовал, от дубликата не спасает..

Comment: А что значит "дублируются"? Они полностью идентичны кроме картинки?

Comment: @Сергей Валерьевич да, все верно, полный дублю кроме картинки

Comment: И сколько запросов у тебя уходит на скрипт аяксом при добавлении отзыва? *Вкладка "Network"

Comment: Спойлер - там при загрузке фото форма отправляется второй раз

Comment: @Сергей Валерьевич один запрос. До экспериментов с функциями в `php` файле отправки фото, отзыв регистрировался только один. У вас есть идеи как исправить?

Comment: добавил `js`. Если прописываю `e.preventDefault();`, то отправляется отзыв только 1 раз, но без картинки

Comment: Что-то здесь не так `formData.push({photo: 'photo'});`

Comment: Я нашел ошибку - в форме `html` был прописан `action`, который дополнительно отправлял форму, поэтому отключил `ajax` в принципе. @Алексей  а как должно быть так?

Comment: Вы в photo просто строку передаете, а не переменную. Местами поменяйте кавычки `formData.push({'photo': photo})`;

Comment: `wp_insert_post` и `media_handle_upload` не связаны с друг другом, вторая - обертка для `wp_insert_attachment`
Раз записей две, логично что запрос к add_review.php происходит дважды
Перепиши ajax через [средства wordpress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html)